# VBA docmd.Transferspreadsheet Loop fails (with no error) on 3rd and 4th loop only, then resumes to work

Tags: ms-access, vba

--- This code should loop through a recordset created with unique records (sub_nbr) from a tbl_ccg_all_sub.  During the loop, it exports the data associated with a given sub_nbr to an excel template already saved (Select * where loop#=sub_nbr).  It will work until the 3rd loop, where it stupidly transfers the same data from the previous loop into the spreadsheet.  It then resumes working on the 5th or 6th loop.  Craziness!!!

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim v As String
Dim objfso As Object

Set objfso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("select distinct sub_nbr from tbl_ccg_all_sub")

Dim strqry As String
Dim qdftemp As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strQdf As String

strQdf = "_TempQuery_"
Do While Not rs1.EOF
    v = rs1.Fields(0).Value    
    strqry = "select * from tbl_ccg_all_sub where sub_nbr = '" & v & "'"
    Set qdftemp = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strQdf, strqry)
    qdftemp.Close
    Set qdftemp = Nothing
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Users\U557687\Desktop\test_db\test_template.xlsx"   

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, strQdf, filename, True
    DoEvents     
    objfso.copyfile filename, "C:\Users\U557687\Desktop\Test_db\" & v & ".xlsx"

    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete strQdf
    rs1.MoveNext
 Loop
 rs1.Close
```

Comment: please help!!!!

Comment: Here is the question all programmers are afraid to answer.  If you can solve this riddle, you are the greatest in the galaxy.

Comment: I finally got around to debugging this and it works 100% now.  Transferspreadsheet is very finicky and doesn't like overwriting 'all' the time.  The solution was a simple clear contents command in my loop :)  I will uploaded the corrected VBA shortly.  Great way export data for multiple filters in a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

''''' This example creates an index of unique values in a dataset.  It then loops through the index, exports to .xls template file (already saved somewhere), and saves a copy of the template using the distinct value.  I use this to create a separate file for each client I have.  One tab in my sheet contains formulas linked to the tab that will be updated by each client's data.  Bam.  You're welcome.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim v As String
Dim objfso As Object

Set objfso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("select distinct sub_nbr from tbl_ccg_all_sub")

Dim strqry As String
Dim qdftemp As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strQdf As String



Do While Not rs1.EOF

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application


With xlApp
    .Visible = False ''''REMINDER: CHANGE THIS TO FALSE WHEN CODING COMPLETE
    Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\poop\Desktop\test_db\test_template.xlsx", , False)
    .Sheets("_tempquery_").Cells.ClearContents ''''FORMATTING MAINTAINED, ONLY CONTENTS ARE CLEARED
    xlWB.Close True


End With



'''Workbooks("C:\Users\poop\Desktop\test_db\test_template.xlsx").Close True

''Stop




strQdf = "_TempQuery_"

v = rs1.Fields(0).Value
strqry = "select * from tbl_ccg_all_sub where sub_nbr = '" & v & "'"
Set qdftemp = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(strQdf, strqry)
qdftemp.Close
Set qdftemp = Nothing
Dim filename As String
filename = "C:\Users\poop\Desktop\test_db\test_template.xlsx"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, strQdf, filename, True
DoEvents

CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete strQdf

''''Stop

objfso.copyfile filename, "C:\Users\poop\Desktop\Test_db\" & v & ".xlsx"

''''Stop

 rs1.MoveNext
 Loop
 rs1.Close
```